# NameError: name 'alg' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7

In Python I am running code to define a function. the first part appears to run ok but the second part throws a 'name not defined' error.
Here is the code;` #This this part runs fine.

```
 def modelfit(alg, dtrain, predictors, performCV=True, printFeatureImportance=True, cv_folds=5):
    #Fit the algorithm on the data
```

alg.fit(dtrain[predictors], dtrain['Target'])
    # the part below this is where the error gets thrown

```
# Predict training set:
```

dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(dtrain[predictors])
dtrain_predprob = alg.predict_proba(dtrain[predictors])[:,1]

Here is the complete error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-edfedf10fb86> in <module>()
      1 #Predict training set:
----> 2 dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(dtrain[predictors])
      3 dtrain_predprob = alg.predict_proba(dtrain[predictors])[:,1]

NameError: name 'alg' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your *actual* code? Then I'm surprised that's the only error you get. What is that leading single quote `'` doing in those lines? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Joachim, all of the other code worked (not sure how the tic got in there) but am only concerned about the snippet that threw the error.

Comment: @Dfox use the [edit] link to post the code in your question, then use the code-formatting button `{}` to make it correctly formatted. Use the preview below the editing box to make sure everything looks good.

Comment: @Dfox like I said previously, please do not post code in comments. Click this link here -> [edit] and put the code into your question. Highlight the code, then click the `{}` button above the editing box to format it properly. There is a preview below the editing box - make sure everything is properly formatted before hitting the `Save Edits` button at the bottom.

Comment: @MattDMo, Just realized that you had already edited my code- thanks! Hopefully it makes my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the indentation of this function definition is not aligned. The "alg" is a variable defined by the function "modelfit", and indented out of alignment is considered a new variable outside the function.What you shoule do is just to adjust the indentation.